# Open Source Cocoa/Cocoa-Touch POP3/SMTP library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, pop3

I'm looking to write a sample application speaking to a POP3/SMTP server. Instead of re-inventing the wheel with BSD sockets and CFNetwork type calls, I'm curious if there is currently any open source libraries that already take care of alot of the dirty work? I've tried Googling without much luck for anything.

Perhaps there's something I'm overlooking to simplify this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[MessageFramework on CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MessageFramework) lists various possibilities,

["Sending emails from Cocoa"](http://vafer.org/blog/20080604120118) also lists several frameworks, including [Pantomime](http://www.collaboration-world.com/pantomime/), [MailCore](http://www.libmailcore.com) and EdMessage (the [site for this](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/EDFrameworks/) seems to be down, but there is a [mirror on github](http://github.com/tcurdt/edmessage/tree/master), which has also been modified to compile for 10.4, as well as 10.5 - so should work on the iPhone)

Example code using Pantomime (from the above blog-post):

```
CWMessage *message = [[CWMessage alloc] init];

CWInternetAddress *address;

address = [[CWInternetAddress alloc] initWithString:@"from@gmail.com"];
[message setFrom:address];
[address release];

address = [[CWInternetAddress alloc] initWithString:@"to@somewhere.com"];
[address setType:PantomimeToRecipient];
[message addRecipient:address];
[address release];

[message setSubject:@"test"];

[message setContentType: @"text/plain"];
[message setContentTransferEncoding: PantomimeEncodingNone];
[message setCharset: @"us-ascii"];

[message setContent: [@"This is a simple content." dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

smtp = [[CWSMTP alloc] initWithName:@"smtp.gmail.com" port:465];
[smtp setDelegate: self];
[smtp setMessage: message];
[message release];

ssl = YES;
mechanism = @"PLAIN";

[smtp connectInBackgroundAndNotify];
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is one. I have not tried it myself, but you can give it a shot...

http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at OmniGroup's [open source frameworks](http://www.omnigroup.com/developer/), in particular the OmniNetworking framework. There are also a lot of other awesome components in their other frameworks you might consider using.