# Send email directly in background in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [iPhone send email not using MessageUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172299/iphone-send-email-not-using-messageui)
>   [Locking the Fields in MFMailComposeViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284599/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-question-locking-the-fields)

I want to send email directly from iphone/ipad without user visibility.
I mean I want to send my email without opening MFMailcomposser sheet.

Is this possible?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5183267/876283

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, you have to send email from server side.

So, whatever data you want to send in email, you just pass it to web-service and from there, send email to user.

This is only way by which user will not know, that email has been sent. And no default "MFMailcomposser" will be opened.