# Sending email without showing email composer view in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, email

I'm making an iOS app and the user has to enter their info to register for an account. I'm wanting to make it so that it sends an email to the provided email account with the info that they just entered. But I don't want them to be able to see the email view. Is there a way to send an email in the background in iOS 7? I'm familiar with the SMTP Gmail workaround but I was wondering if there was anything more generic.

Comment: Simply submit the data to your web server. No need for SMTP

Comment: You cannot do that without accept from user.

Comment: There is a solution for this. Please see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172299/iphone-send-email-not-using-messageui/5183267#5183267

Answer (score 3):

There is no documented API available using which you can perform this.

send this detail to your server via web service and than server will send the email using that detail.