# Send email without user interaction in iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I know you can send an email out of your app by presenting the user with a `MFMailComposeViewController`, but can you also send an email without the user having to push any send buttons?

Comment: You can’t send an email from the user without their involvement. You can send an email from your own address using something like [mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com)

Comment: your question is not much clear! When you exactly want to send mail ?

Comment: No it's not possible with the users configured E-Mail on his phone. But... you can can send a mail from your backend from a general address...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is "No".

It is against Apple guidelines. You cannot send mail without user interaction (action on send button).

As an alternate option, you can use power of web server/web service. Send information/data to your web service using web service request and can send an email from you web server. (Note: Mail sender id will not be email id of application user.)

You can try this but remember, it's against Apple guidelines and Apple may reject your app.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183267/5638630
- http://iosameer.blogspot.in/2013/01/sending-e-mail-in-background-from-ios_25.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6287412/5638630

Comment: Instead of posting an answer with links to duplicates,  you should have just voted to close the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually not possible to send an email only using your iOS code without MFMailComposeViewController and user's explicit interaction.

But you could upload the content of your mail to a web service of your own or from a third party and that will send it for you. This way the user will not do anything.