# How to send email from iPhone app without user interface

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, attachment

I want my app to be able to send an email with attachment to a hard-coded recipient with no user input required, unlike the MessageUI framework.

Is there any way to do this? Any example code would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Saurabh said, there is no low level mail library. I would look for an SMTP library, rather than an IMAP one, because you don't need to get mail, just sent it.

Attachments can be done with MFMailComposeViewController's via `-(void)addAttachmentData:(NSData *)attachment mimeType:(NSString *)mimeType fileName:(NSString *)filename`

Which I believe simply base64 encodes the data, and attached a mime type header and footer.

Check out this question for lots on the topic: [Open Source Cocoa/Cocoa-Touch POP3/SMTP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740939/open-source-cocoa-cocoa-touch-pop3-smtp-library)

Answer (score 6):

Apple doesn't give you a way to do this. You'll have to write your own IMAP library or use a 3rd-party library ([Mailcore](http://www.mronge.com/m/MailCore/) is good).

Comment: How can I attach a file to the email?

Comment: cduck: MFMailComposeViewController has a method `- (void)addAttachmentData:(NSData *)attachment mimeType:(NSString *)mimeType fileName:(NSString *)filename`

Comment: Mailcore (more specifically, CTCoreMessage) doesn't have built-in attachment support as far as I know.