# iPhone in-App email

Tags: iphone, email

I am using iPhone in-App email feature to send email thru my app. 
The email goes fine but I am having hard time trying to figure out how to retrive email addresses to which the email was sent.
Here is my code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self; 
[picker setSubject:@"Test"];

// Fill out the email body text
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a test data"];

[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack; 

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

Is there any way to retrive those email addresses from this function:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot. This is private information.

You could make your own e-mail entry form and then pre-fill to field of the `MFMailComposeViewController` using `- (void)setToRecipients:(NSArray*)toRecipients`. But you cannot sure that the user doesn't change the address once `MFMailComposeViewController` is shown.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080278/how-to-send-email-from-iphone-app-without-user-interface/2080288#2080288) to a similar question suggests using custom IMAP libary like [Mailcore](http://www.mronge.com/m/MailCore/) instead of built in `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Comment: Good point. It is indeed private info which Apple might want to protect. So, I guess I'll have to handle sending of emails thru my backend code. Only problem would be to grab emails from already existing contacts.
Mailcore seems like a good alternative... I'll check that out.
Well, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the `MFMailComposeViewController` documentation I see only methods to set the recipients.

I think that this is probably a very deliberate move by Apple to prevent the misuse of personal information, much in the same way that Apple does not allow a developer to fetch a user's mobile number programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible.  There are no public properties in a MFMailComposeViewController besides the delegate, and it only seems to have setter methods and no getters.