# write own mail client to send Mail using SMTP/POP3 server on iphone

Tags: iphone, sendmail

I am trying to develop application to send mail using configured SMTP client rather than iPhone's default MailController.

How can i implement this functionality? Is it possible to design such client?

Thanks,

Jim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, however, unless you want to develop your own implementation of the protocols and start opening TCP ports, etc, you might want to look into OSS tools that provide these features.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740939/open-source-cocoa-cocoa-touch-pop3-smtp-library) might help you out.

Comment: Thanks for reply.can you please give some tutorial link to start with?