# iPhone: how to send email from iPhone withouth use MFMailComposeViewController Class?

Tags: iphone

does it possible to send email without use MFMailComposeViewController Class that provide by Apple ? whether app will accept this type app ?

if it is no problem to publish , which open source lib code can be use for this purpose ?

thanks for your help or tip .

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to send email without showing compose email UI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968635/how-to-send-email-without-showing-compose-email-ui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of open source libraries that provide mail sending functionality. Using the libraries themselves should not be grounds for rejection from the App Store, but you should take care about how and what you send by email. Especially you should make it clear to the user that emails are sent, and that you do not send of anything compromising the users personal privacy.

The most popular email library seems to be 
[skpsmtpmessage](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/). There is also a library called [Pantomime](http://www.collaboration-world.com/pantomime) but it has not been officially ported to iPhone, so denending on your needs you might be better off with the first choice.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply , if any open source code also support POP3 but only SMTP ? thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The three20 framework does this (http://www.three20.info) and it is all open source so try that out.  Apple only provides `MFMailComposeViewController`