# Send E-mail from An Application iOS 4.0 and above

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new at iPhone application development..I am developing an application in which user has to enter E-mail in text box and on clicking button e-mail should be sent to an address..Hope this description is enough to understand my requirements.. 
"I DO NOT WANT TO OPEN MAIL COMPOSER TEMPLATE.. MAIL SHOULD BE DIRECTLY SENT ON CLICKING BUTTON"

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You will have to provide your own SMTP server in most cases.  You can't send an email through the user's mail without going through the mail composer.  I'm guessing the reason for this is that Apple wants to ensure the user knows that an email is being sent out through their own account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: how to send email from iPhone withouth use MFMailComposeViewController Class ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184179/iphone-how-to-send-email-from-iphone-withouth-use-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-cl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do from following **[SkpSMTPMessage](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/)**.

Comment: You need to get sample project from this link. http://skpsmtpmessage.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ It include all the library you need to use. It is very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own Server-Side PHP client to handle emailing. I did this in one of my apps, and it works perfectly.

Comment: No, I am not your slave. Go and make it yourself.

Comment: well i am new at this..i just learned iOS 5 days ago..Thats why.. :(btw thanks for help..

Comment: The script isn't PHP, and again, I will not post you my code. You should be learning how to do this rather than having the 'give me teh codez' attitude, so therefore I have no sympathy.