# iphone send in-app mail automatically

Tags: iphone, email

In iPhone programming, there are two ways to send mail.
1. openURL
2. In-App mail using messageUI framework.

Using second approach - in-app mail, it will show a view with to address, subject and body of message. Then it will have "Send" and "Cancel" buttons. On click of send button, message will be sent and then it will come back to app.

Now my question is that, is there any possiblity to send mail automatically without showing the view and clicking "send" button?

Because, I want to send 10 custom messages to 10 different email id's one after another. Possible or not?

Comment: this might be helpful... a similar question with good resources

Comment: forgot to add link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740939/open-source-cocoa-cocoa-touch-pop3-smtp-library

Comment: Now using messageUI framework we can send SMS also, Can I also send SMS using the link you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to build-in your own mail agent code to connect to a mail server, and have the user enter all necessary account credentials into your app (or have your own account built-in).

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The message sender interface forces you to allow the user a cancel or send option - this is to prevent apps spamming with the user's account.

Comment: This is however if you only wanted to use the messageUI framework. You may be able to use other methods to achieve this, including but not limited to PHP scripts with the sendmail() function implemented running on your web server. You could call these with NSURL and NS whatnots for the connections the the HTTP page.

Comment: Isn't there a way to at least display the mail composer without giving the user the ability to change the content or subject ?