# Webservice for sending email

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, email

I am looking for 3rd party webservice that we can use to send emails. I don't want to use MFMailComposer or skpsmtpmessage libraries. Preferably ones that are easy to integrate with iOS devices.

Comment: There are couple of decent methods on here you look at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740939/open-source-cocoa-cocoa-touch-pop3-smtp-library

Answer (score 0):

How about [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/)? There is an [Objective C binding](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/#objc) for it and it's free (up to a certain limit).