# Want to send mail without USing MFmailcomposer and without webservice

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a task which is  related to sending mail without connection or MFmailcomposer.
Simply i am doing work on a form which have to sent a single mail-id. when the form fills up and user perform the action for sending then sent mail to the client without MFmailcomposer and webservice if connection available else if Wi-fi is not available then filled form text file will save in documents directory.and when iPhone comes in connection then automatically it sent to that mail -id. document is saving as text file. but now what to do ?
Is SMTP is useful for it?
suggest me...

Comment: Well forget about ['MFMailComposeViewController'](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) you will have to with `SMTP`.

Comment: You won't be able to send the mail automatically when it connects via wi-fi unless your app is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below link could help you...

http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-testing-network-reachability/

Answer (score 1):

You would definitely have to implement this functionality with SMTP.

Check the answer to this SO Post, [Open Source Cocoa/Cocoa-Touch POP3/SMTP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740939/open-source-cocoa-cocoa-touch-pop3-smtp-library)

Includes several links to different SMTP Libraries, as well as example code.