# Custom mail sending other than MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone, sendmail, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Is there any other way to send custom mail.

[image]

In my application i want to send mail like this

[image: my custom design]

How can i implement this custom view for sending mails.

Answer (score 2):

Check this answer:

[Open Source Cocoa/Cocoa-Touch POP3/SMTP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740939/open-source-cocoa-cocoa-touch-pop3-smtp-library)

It's more complex than using the MailComposer, but it's possible

also you can use this library:

https://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/